# Displaying rgb8 pixel data in-browser

Tags: html, image, canvas, ros

I have found similar questions to mine on SO, but have not yet come across an answer to this problem. I have a rgb8 encoded image that I am trying to display in-browser, either in an `img` or `canvas` element. I am unsure how to convert this pixel data into an image properly, and was looking for any insight.

For context, the source of this rgb8 data is from a ROS topic with type `sensor_msgs/Image`. When subscribing to this topic using `roslibjs`, I am given the following object:

```
{
  data: “MT4+CR…”, (of length 1228800)
  encoding: "rgb8",
  header: {
    frame_id: “camera_color_optical_frame”,
    seq: 1455,
    stamp: ...timestamp info
  },
  height: 480,
  is_bigendian: 0,
  step: 1920,
  width: 640
}
```

With the `data` string, I have tried displaying it on canvas, converting it to base64, etc. but have not been able to. I know about `web_video_server` in ROS to help send these images over a port, but that is not an option for me unfortunately - I need to work directly with the `data`.

Is there a way I can go about displaying this rgb8 data in the browser? Based on the documentation on [here](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html), `data` should be represented as a `uint8[]` (if that helps).

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a canvas of the correct size and obtain a [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)

```
// Assuming that imgMes is the image message as linked in question

const can = document.createElement("canvas");
can.width = imgMes.width;
can.height = imgMes.height; 
const ctx = can.getcontext("2d");
```

Then create an [image buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createImageData) to hold the pixels

```
const imgData = ctx.createImageData(0, 0, imgMes.width, imgMes.height);
const data = imgData.data;
const inData = imgMes.data;
```

Then read the data from the image message. Making sure to use the correct order as defined in the flag `is_bigendian`

```
var i = 0, j, y = 0, x;
while (y < imgMes.height) {
    j = y * imgMes.step;
    for (x = 0; x < imgMes.width; x ++) {
        if (imgMes.is_bigendian) {
            data[i]     = inData[j];     // red
            data[i + 1] = inData[j + 1]; // green
            data[i + 2] = inData[j + 2]; // blue
        } else {
            data[i + 2] = inData[j];     // blue
            data[i + 1] = inData[j + 1]; // green
            data[i]     = inData[j + 2]; // red
        }
        data[i + 3] = 255;  // alpha
        i += 4;
        j += 3;
     }
     y++;
 }
```

The [put the pixel data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) into the canvas;

```
 ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

And add the canvas to your HTML

```
 document.body.appendChild(can);
```

And you are done.

Note that I may have is_bigendian the wrong way around. If so just change the line `if (imgMes.is_bigendian) {` to `if (!imgMes.is_bigendian) {`

### UPDATE

With more information regarding the data format i was able to extract the image.

I used [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) to decode the Base64 string. This returns another string. I then iterated each character in the string, getting the character code to add to each pixel.

It is unclear where the endianess is. My guess is that it is in the decoded string and thus the code swaps bytes for each char code as it makes no sense to have endianess on multiples of 3 bytes

```
const can = document.createElement("canvas");
can.width = imgMes.width;
can.height = imgMes.height;
const ctx = can.getContext("2d");

const imgData = ctx.createImageData(imgMes.width, imgMes.height);
const data = imgData.data;
const inData = atob(imgMes.data);

var j = 0; i = 4; // j data in , i data out
while( j < inData.length) {
    const w1 = inData.charCodeAt(j++);  // read 3 16 bit words represent 1 pixel
    const w2 = inData.charCodeAt(j++);
    const w3 = inData.charCodeAt(j++);
    if (!imgMes.is_bigendian) {
        data[i++] = w1; // red
        data[i++] = w2; // green
        data[i++] = w3; // blue
    } else {
        data[i++] = (w1 >> 8) + ((w1 & 0xFF) << 8);
        data[i++] = (w2 >> 8) + ((w2 & 0xFF) << 8);
        data[i++] = (w3 >> 8) + ((w3 & 0xFF) << 8);
    }
    data[i++] = 255;  // alpha
}

ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
document.body.appendChild(can);
```

From the example data I got an image of some paving near a road.

Comment: Hi there,

Thank you for your response! I've tried this, and I end up with a fully black canvas - it appears that nothing is being copied over into `data` properly. I also tried to reverse the `is_bigendian` check, to no avail. My `imgMes.data` is a string - is there any conversion I have to make prior to setting the `inData` variable, maybe?

Comment: @Imas Can you provide a sample of the `imgMes.data`

Comment: @Imas you can also try `const inData = imgMes.data.split(",").map(Number)` to convert comma delimited string to numbers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Splitting on comma didn't seem to work - I don't believe there are any commas in this string. Here is a link to a sandbox with an example image I'm working with: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-feynman-3h6nr.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey @BlindMan67! I was playing around with this solution a bit more, as I was curious to see whether I can represent my image in an `<img>` tag. I was able to do so, by calling `var dataURL = can.toDataURL()`, then setting `img.src = dataURL`. Do you know if there's any earlier step in your process that allows one to directly get to a base64-encoded image (the `dataURL` appears to look like `data:image/png;base64,...`) as opposed to setting the canvas first? Just curious!

Comment: @Imas For raw pixel data there is no way to avoid the canvas.